# Help identify this mixte

Tags: identify-this-bike, mixte

A mixte frame with bcn stamped on front, 224 stamped on bottom of frame, Mafac racer brake calipers, Simplex shifters, Suntour derailleuers and hubs, Weinmann brake levers.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: ID: Cheap department store bicycle circa 1970s.

Comment: @RoboKaren dunno - a 3 digit serial number seems far too small for a chain store bike.

Comment: @acostello could you post a whole-bike picture too please?  Your detail photos are good.  Can't see BB or brakes or stem or chainrings in any shots.   Nice brakes suggest its more than a BSO of the day.

Comment: Detail of the fork crown, and general lack of surface rust does not suggest BSO to me.

Comment: Yes, I will post new images of the bike when I get back home.

Comment: The stamped sheet metal lug connecting the seat stay and seat tube is what pushed me in the department store direction.

Comment: Posted a few more pics. Was hoping it wasn't department store. But cant seem to find any info on it

Comment: Whatever it is, its a loverly bike.  The brakes and lugwork and fork crown look quality.   Slap some wheels under it and fresh bartape, new brake pads, and cables if they're rusty.  If you want to be period correct, that alloy rear rack and kickstand are probably too new.    Also, I note that whoever cabled the brakes did it racer-style, up and over the bars not in front of them, which implies many good things and nothing bad.  Nice find!

Comment: Definitely 70s, or maybe earlier.  Not real high quality, but decent.  Lugged construction was later to become a sign of a better quality bike, but most bikes of that era were lugged, as the techniques used for modern welded frames had not been developed yet.  The crankset has been replaced.

Comment: @Acostello it is what it is.  If you have the time its worth fixing up.  If you don't have time, pass it to someone who can fix it.  Its too nice to scrap.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but it looks a lot like a motobecane to me.

Comment: Some reasoning would be helpful, here. Do the decals match Motobecane? Googling for "motobecane decals" doesn't give anything looking like those.

Comment: I'd say it's a good guess - the front fork crown lug shape are is typical Motobecane from the '70s and the early '80s if I'm not mistaken. Now let's only find a Motobecane catalogue and spot the exact model.

Answer (score -1):

It's clearly a workshop bike from the 70's, numbers are not SN but references for the tubing. It's merely impossible to go further in part because there has been obvious part replacement (front rear) and common old parts (brakes).

Sorry

Comment: You're suggesting its made from "224 tubing"  ?  What is that?

Comment: No it's more likely something that was used in the factory construction process

Comment: The 224 number was stamped after the bike was painted. Long after - see the paint chips around the digits. It has thus nothing to make with the type of tubing. Motobecane did however use 2040 high tensile steel for their frames.